# Trying to have grep tell me which values are not present, from a foreach loop

Tags: unix, foreach, grep, sh

I am trying to write a simple foreach loop that would list which files are present and which are not in a directory. For this example, let's pretend we have a directory with two files called def_456 and ghi_789. If I were to do something like this:

```
foreach f (`xargs`)
abc
def
ghi
foreach$ ls /path/to/dir/* | grep $f
foreach$ end
```

I would expect it to spit out `def_456 ghi_789` since this directory does not have file called abc_123.  Is there a way to have it let me know that `abc_123` is missing? Is there a flag I can use with grep or something else that will tell which of my list in the foreach loop were not present?

Thanks!

Edited to hopefully make this question more clear and to remove the bash tag and add the sh tag. I hope this is correct. As you can all tell I am quite a noob when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Btw, `bash` doesn't have a foreach loop

Comment: maybe `ls /path/to/dir/*` will always output (e.g.) /path/to/dir/s where an a is contained anyway (in path)? So any chars in /path/to/dir would always be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return code of grep will tell you - if $? after grep is 0 then what you grepped was present, if it is 1 it was not present

So

```
foreach f (`xargs`)
abc
def
ghi
foreach$ ls /path/to/dir/* | grep -q $f
foreach$ test $? -eq 1 && echo $f
foreach$ end
```

will revert the output - it should print what is *not* found - not sure though if that is what you wanted....

Comment: Yes thank you so much, this did exactly what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not `grep`, but the [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) utility might be useful. It compares two sorted files line by line. If you have your list of files that you're looking for in a file called `a`, and the list of things that were actually there in `b`, you could do `comm a b`:

> With  no  options, [comm produces] three-column output. Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.

If you hide two of these columns, you end up with a plain listing.

`comm -12 a b`: Only print entries the files had in common (hide columns one and two)

`comm -13 a b`: Only print entries unique to the second file (`d f g s` in your example)

`comm -23 a b`: Only entries unique to the first file (`a` in your example)

Of course, you can use Bash `<(command)` syntax to read from commands instead of real files. It should work the same, and you can easily tack on a `| sort` if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since my question was a little vague, your suggestion didn't actually work quite how I wanted it to. The list I am giving the foreach loop only contains a part of the file name. I should have been more specific. Sorry about that! I have edited the question now.